# Python regex and escape characters

Tags: python, regex

I have the following regex code:

```
tmp = 'c:\\\\temp'
  m = re.search(tmp, tmp)
  if(m==None):
      print('Unable to find a ticker in ' + filename)
  else:
      print("REGEX RESULT - " + m.group(0))
```

which returns None. No matter how many or few backslashes I use for variable tmp, I still get None as result. How can I perform regex to search for a backslashed file path?

Comment: Shouldn't you search in `filename` instead of in `tmp`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use r'' to ignore escape chars

```
tmp = r'c:\\temp'
```

r is for raw string